RSA Enryption in .NET 4.8 using RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256
In .NET 8, I am using the following RSA encryption code (simplified):
    public static string EncryptWithPublicKey(string text, string keyString)
    {
        var rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(keyString), out _);
        var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(dataBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
    }

    public static string DecryptWithPrivateKey(string cipherText, string keyString)
    {
        var rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(keyString), out _);
        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }

    public static KeyPair GenerateKeyPair()
    {
        using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        {
            return new KeyPair() { PrivateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey()), PublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey()) };
        }           
    }

I need to back port this to a .NET 4.8 project, but it appears that the framework only seems to support SHA1 - is that the case?
I have tried using bouncy castle and extensions like https://gist.github.com/valep27/4a720c25b35fff83fbf872516f847863 which have enabled me to do basic key generation and then some encryption / decryption using RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1 but I need to support SHA256. Does anyone have any examples of this as I am a bit stuck!
UPDATE
The code I am using in my .net project uses the link above and looks like this:
public static string EncryptWithPublicKey(string text, string keyString)
{
    var rsa = RSAKeys.ImportPublicKey(keyString);
    var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(dataBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}

public static KeyPair GenerateKeyPair()
{
    var rsacp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
 
    var privateKey = RSAKeys.ExportPrivateKey(rsacp);
    var publicKey = RSAKeys.ExportPublicKey(rsacp);

    return new KeyPair() { PrivateKey = privateKey, PublicKey = publicKey };   
}

But when it runs the encryption method it says 'Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.' If I change the padding to to SHA1, it works

only seems to support SHA1 wrong. As the docs show, the padding mode OaepSHA256 is supported in all .NET Framework versions still in support, ie 4.6 and later. Perhaps even earlier. As for hashing, SHA256 was always supported in the .NET Framework 4.x versions

What's the real problem? Why do you assume you can't use RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256 ?

I have updated my original post to explain why it appears to only support SHA1 padding

That's a different question. Why doesn't RSA work with OaepSHA256 in .NET Framework. .NET Core 8 and 9 use OS libraries for encryption, so what works depends on OS support, and SHA2 padding is supported almost everywher unless the legacy CAPI provider is used on Windows. RsaCng should be the default implementation even on .NET Framework, unless some setting changed this. You can try using new RsaCng()

That's the problem after all. In the .NET Framework Reference Source the RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt only accepts OaepSHA1 while RsaCng.Encrypt accepts all options

Since the .NET Framework does not support PEM/DER encoded keys, it is right to switch to BouncyCastle. However, I would never use the referenced library RSAKeys, as it implements the export very inefficiently. This can be implemented much more compactly with BC's PemWriter. You should also consider using the BouncyCastle classes for encryption and decryption (instead of .NET classes such as RSACng), as this eliminates the need to convert between the BC/.NET data types (and it also automatically solves your primary problem).

Use RSACng instead of the CAPI-based RSACryptoServiceProvider. The docs may warn that RsaCng only works on Windows, but then, so does .NET Framework. As the Cross-Platform Cryptography chart shows the CAPI-based RSACryptoServiceProvider is the only one that doesn't support OaepSHA256.
var rsa=new RSACng();

To avoid hard-coding the algorithm you can pass the algorithm name as a parameter, or specify it through app.config. As the RSA.Create source shows, Create returns whatever algorithm is configured for "System.Security.Cryptography.RSA".
This article explains how the algorithm names are configured and how to change the defaults for System.Security.Cryptography.RSA. You can find the mapping docs here. You can try setting the default to RSACng by adding this to your application's config file:
<mscorlib>
  <cryptographySettings>
    <cryptoNameMapping>
      <cryptoClasses>
        <cryptoClass
          MyRSAImplementation="System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng,
          System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
          PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </cryptoClasses>
      <nameEntry
        name="SomeCustomFriendlyName"
        class="MyRSAImplementation" />
      <nameEntry
        name="System.Security.Cryptography.RSA"
        class="MyRSAImplementation" />
    </cryptoNameMapping>
  </cryptographySettings>
</mscorlib>

or perhaps just
<mscorlib>
  <cryptographySettings>
    <cryptoNameMapping>
      <nameEntry
        name="System.Security.Cryptography.RSA"
        class="System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng" />
    </cryptoNameMapping>
  </cryptographySettings>
</mscorlib>

